# How can i select the last line of a text file using C

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to find out a way to select the last line of a text file using C (not c++ or c#, just C) and I am having a difficult time finding a way to do this, if anyone could assist me with this problem I would be very grateful, thanks! (btw for a good example of what i am trying to do, this would be similar what to tail -n 1 would be doing in bash)

Comment: Simple method: fseek() to the end of the file, then read backwards until you reach a `\n`.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are having problems with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No direct way, but my preferred method is:

1. Go to the end of the file
2. Read last X bytes
3. If they contain '\n' - you got your line - read from that offset to the end of the file
4. Read X bytes before them
5. back to 3 until match found
6. If reached the beginning of the file - the whole file is the last line

Comment: You can simplify it if lines are no longer than some `N`. Just read the last `N` bytes and look for the last `\n` in them.

Comment: thanks for the help! was sort of confused as to how i should go about doing so, made it much easier to understand though (am teaching myself C and figured i would rewrite some log searching bash scripts into C as practice)

Comment: glad to hear! happy coding :)

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fd; // File pointer
    char filename[] = "./Makefile"; // file to read
    char buff[1024];

    if ((fd = fopen(filename, "r")) != NULL) // open file
    {
        fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET); // make sure start from 0

        while(!feof(fd))
        {
            memset(buff, 0x00, 1024); // clean buffer
            fscanf(fd, "%[^\n]\n", buff); // read file *prefer using fscanf
        }
        printf("Last Line :: %s\n", buff);
    }
}
```

I'm using Linux.
CMIIW

Comment: What happens if the last line is not newline terminated?

Answer (score 1):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef max
#define max(a, b) ((a)>(b))? (a) : (b)
#endif

long GetFileSize(FILE *fp){
    long fsize = 0;

    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fsize = ftell(fp); 
    fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET);//reset stream position!!

    return fsize;
}
char *lastline(char *filepath){
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[4096+1];
    int size,i;
    long fsize;
    if(NULL==(fp=fopen(filepath, "r"))){
        perror("file cannot open at lastline");
        return NULL;
    }
    fsize= -1L*GetFileSize(fp);
    if(size=fseek(fp, max(fsize, -4096L), SEEK_END)){
        perror("cannot seek");
        exit(1);
    }
    size=fread(buff, sizeof(char), 4096, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buff[size] = '\0';
    i=size-1;
    if(buff[i]=='\n'){
        buff[i] = '\0';
    }
    while(i >=0 && buff[i] != '\n')
        --i;
    ++i;
    return strdup(&buff[i]);
}

int main(void){
    char *last;

    last = lastline("data.txt");
    printf("\"%s\"\n", last);
    free(last);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assumes that one line is shorter 4096byte.

Comment: This was actually the fastest example provided, will have to do some digging to find out how this one works :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *nix operating system, you can use the command 'last'. See 'last' man page for details.
If you want integrate the functionality inside another program, you can use 'system' call to execute 'last' and get it's result.

Comment: Yep (usually use tail for that) but i was interested in using C completely for doing this, thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

A simple and inefficient way to do it is to read each line into a buffer.
When the last read gives you `EOF`, you have the last line in the buffer.

Binyamin Sharet's suggestion is more efficient, but just a bit harder to implement.